# Symfony2: Using the Finder Component for S3

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3

On [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) I read (scroll down) that you can use Symfony's Finder component to iterate through an S3 bucket like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$s3 = new \Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($key, $secret);
$s3->registerStreamWrapper("s3");

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->name('photos*')->size('< 100K')->date('since 1 hour ago');
foreach ($finder->in('s3://bucket-name') as $file) {
    // ... do something

    print $file->getFilename()."\n";
}
```

But I don't know where to get \Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 class and how to make it work with Symfony since it's not using PHP 5.3 namespaces. I downloaded the new zend framework and found S3.php which inherits some other files. Where do I need to put it and how can I include it?

Sidemark: I found a class (Orchestra S3 Stream) that can also read through S3 buckets, but failed installing it since it uses a pear package where I had some path issues with the files. I think if I can use the Finder component that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend now follow the PSR-0 namespace convention http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/ and you can use only the paquage that you need http://packages.zendframework.com/#composer

Answer (score 0):

This is way old but just FYI you can do this with the AWSSdk class w/o using Zend Framework component if you like (not that I have anything against using ZF).